# Real time data manipulation of excel sheet with Visual studio forms .net

Tags: .net, excel, vb.net, forms

I am working on building a simple app consisting of information regarding part numbers which links dataset stored in excel, displays it appropriately in several text boxes in a form created with vb.net in visual studio, with different. The part numbers are chosen using a Combobox, which refers to the excel sheet.

With the click of a button, I want the content in the cell pertaining to a particular textbox to move to another cell and that to be displayed in real-time in the form and also updates the back-end dataset.

Any idea on how to do this?

I am getting the following error:

`System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'The Microsoft Access database engine could not find the object '{Sheet1}${14}{2}:{14}{2}'. Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly. If '{Sheet1}${14}{2}:{14}{2}' is not a local object, check your network connection or contact the server administrator.'`

Update: I have installed:
Microsoft access Database engine redistributable
and also changed the Platform to X86 from X64 Since I kind of figured out mine runs on 32 bit platform.
I have also changed ACE connection to Jet, enabled IIS to run on 32 bit applications after downloading Access 2010 database Engine 2010, after donwloading it from

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255

With Jet Connection, the error is:

```
The 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.'
```

The code snippet is below:

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
   
    Dim Folder As String = "S:\Special_documents\Window5 - Copy"
    Dim Filename As String = "grocerieslist.xlsx"

    Dim connectionstring As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & Folder & "\" & Filename & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;"""
    Dim MyConnection As New OleDbConnection(connectionstring)
    MyConnection.Open()

    Dim P As New OleDbCommand
    P.Connection = MyConnection


    P.CommandText = "Update [{Sheet1}${14}{2}:{14}{2}] SET F1=Textbox11.text"
    P.ExecuteNonQuery()

    MyConnection.Close()
```

Comment: Show us some code.  That aside, the error message probably gives yo the answer to your problem.  the file is read only

Comment: Hello, I have modified the post,showed some code and also updated the error message .

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18391924/updating-excel-sheet-using-oledb  the answer here looks like might get you heading in the right direction.  Also, think you might have to do something with SET F1=Textbox11.test.  That doesn't look right to me

Comment: Thank you, I have managed to solve this !

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this.
I realized I had to first open a database or excel file for it to update and added a select statement up
However, I am facing issues with transferring real-time date onto the excel sheet.

The data value is stored as a string variable and yet the update statement does not recognize the date as it is but converts it into a string and as a result I get a random output in the excel sheet- most often it is 01/01/1900.

The code snippet is below:

```
Dim thisdate as date
date=today 
Dim thedate as string
thedate=date  
command = New OleDbCommand("UPDATE[sheet1$C" & rownumber & ":C" & rownumber & "] SET F1=" + thedate + "", MyConnection)
command.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Looking forward for your feedback and comments